# Regex: Only match base.extension filenames

Tags: regular-expressions

I would like to match all filenames with only one dot in them:

```
(re-search-forward "[a-z0-9A-Z]?+\\.dsp$")

bdsp
plop.dsp.zzz
plop.1.dsp
plop.dsp
```

Here, the regexp matches `plop.1.dsp`, but it should ignore that and match nothing but the last line, `plop.dsp`.

Any Elisp regexp gurus around to enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `M-x re-builder` to construct your regexp visually.

To match the stuff described in your question, you just have to add `^` at the beginning of your regex.  Then it starts at the beginning of the line.

```
(re-search-forward "^[a-z0-9A-Z]?+\\.dsp$")
```

Answer (score 4):

Different filesystems impose different restrictions on filenames. If the only condition you care about is the presence of exactly one dot with at least one other character before and after the dot, the correct regular expression is

```el
"\\`[^.]+\\.[^.]+\\'"
```

If you also want the file extension to be `dsp`, then you can use

```el
"\\`[^.]+\\.dsp\\'"
```

Using your sample filenames:

```el
(mapcar (lambda (filename)
          (list filename (string-match-p "\\`[^.]+\\.dsp\\'" filename)))
        '("bdsp"
          "plop.dsp.zzz"
          "plop.1.dsp"
          "plop.dsp"))

  ;; => (("bdsp" nil)
  ;;     ("plop.dsp.zzz" nil)
  ;;     ("plop.1.dsp" nil)
  ;;     ("plop.dsp" 0))
```

If you prefer, you can also construct these regexps using the `rx` macro:

```el
(rx bos (+ (not (in ?.))) ?. (+ (not (in ?.))) eos)
  ;; => "\\`[^.]+\\.[^.]+\\'"
(rx bos (+ (not (in ?.))) ".dsp" eos)
  ;; => "\\`[^.]+\\.dsp\\'"
```

Note:

1. When matching buffer lines, e.g. using `re-search-forward`, you should anchor your regexp with

   ```el
   ^ and $
   ```

   to denote the beginning and end of each line, respectively. When matching filename strings as per my examples, however, it is instead better to use

   ```el
   \\` and \\'
   ```

   to denote the beginning and end of the string, respectively. This protects you from the theoretical possibility of matching filenames containing newline characters.
2. In order for the single dot restriction to work for an arbitrary filename, the regular expression must be matched against the non-directory part of the given filename, e.g.

   ```el
   (string-match-p "\\`[^.]+\\.dsp\\'" "~/foo.bar/baz.dsp")
     ;; => nil
   (string-match-p "\\`[^.]+\\.dsp\\'" (file-name-nondirectory "~/foo.bar/baz.dsp"))
     ;; => 0
   ```

Comment: You example returned `eval: Search failed: "\\`[^.]+\\.dsp\\'"` but I upvoted you anyway for your thorough and quick answer :)

Comment: @yassinphilip How are you using that regexp? In a buffer with `re-search-forward` or against a string with `string-match`/`string-match-p`/`replace-regexp-in-string` etc.? In the former case you should use the `^` and `$` anchors. In the latter case there should be two backslashes before the backtick at the start of the regexp.

Comment: @yassinphilip To clarify, in a buffer containing the filenames you list, this should work: `(re-search-forward "^[^.]+\\.dsp$")`. Unless I'm missing something, that is.